# "Error reporting WTF" in logcat error

Tags: android, logcat

While running the android project, I got the  error with text "Error reporting WTF"
The logcat shows:

```
Level         Tag                                  Text
  E      AndroidRuntime                       "Error reporting WTF"
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Oh yeah. What's the question?

Comment: I am not sure but WTF stands for **What a Terrible Failure**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752642/under-what-circumstances-will-androids-log-wtf-terminate-my-app

Comment: When you get an error that you cannot diagnose on your own, please provide a code snippet and the line number on which the error occurred and a more detailed error message (perhaps a stack trace).

Comment: IMO this is a legitimate question. Android has WTF exceptions.

Comment: Good to know it's not just an easter egg from Android. It's a real question.

Answer (score 8):

It may be referring to the `wtf()` function in `android.util.Log`.  Although clearly named for its comical effect, "wtf" is an abbreviation for "What a Terrible Failure" in the Android world, although it's only supposed to be used in error cases that should never really happen in real life usage scenarios.

See here for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29