# Logcat full of "Wtf, activity ActivityRecord" entries

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am getting thousands of the following warning message in my logcat, and it's crowding out the messages that I'm actually looking for:

```
W/ActivityManager﹕ Wtf, activity ActivityRecord{4338cd90 u0 us.bridgeses.Minder.debug/us.bridgeses.Minder.MainListActivity t269 f} in proc activity list not using proc ProcessRecord{4289a348 4821:us.bridgeses.Minder.debug/u0a246}?!?
```

Possibly related, my phone is now occassionally popping up the "Waiting for debugger process" dialog even when my phone is unplugged and the app is in the background. It only stops if I uninstall it, and starts up again the next time I debug. Any ideas?

### Edit:

I just commented out my entire `MainListActivity` class. My app is now literally doing nothing except creating an empty `Activity`. I'm still getting tons of this message, and I'm still getting this message.

### Edit 2:

This is getting really weird. I *uninstalled* the debug app, did not reinstall it, and I'm still getting this message.

Comment: Try `git grep 'Wtf, activity'` or the equivalent for your project - I'd be somewhat surprised if that's coming from library code.

Comment: It's not coming from mine. git grep returns no results.

Comment: It's telling you "wtf is wrong with your code". It's honestly not a big deal and it's as important as other general logcat messages, that is: **it's not important.**

Comment: It may not be important, but it is dumping literally hundreds of them every minute and I have to filter them out or my logcat is unreadable

Comment: I spoke too soon about something I know little about: apparently `wtf` is a (very high) log level in Android ("What a Terrible Failure"). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752642/under-what-circumstances-will-androids-log-wtf-terminate-my-app) contains a bit more information - something is causing an error which may or may not be important but is being logged as if it is a fatal error.

Comment: Then I would really like to know what the cause is. Grep confirms that 'wtf' appears nowhere in my code, so I'm definitely not throwing it. MainListActivity, which it references, is little more than a fragment frame which has not changed in weeks. I think this is more related to problems I've been having with Android Studio 1.2 than my code.

Comment: Well, I would have liked it to be related to the problems I'm having with Android Studio, but I just loaded it into IntelliJ IDEA and have the same error. Android Studio is built on IDEA, so it could be present in both, but Occam says there's something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my phone and the error has not recurred for 10 minutes. It's not really an answer, but I guess it's a resolution.

Answer (score 4):

This message comes from the Android OS. It happens when your activity is not destroyed correctly. Therefore the ActivityRecord is still there, but the corresponding proc is not. By rebooting, all records will lost, so you would not see any of these errors.

Typically this happens when a active/foreground activity component is being disabled. Such as calling `packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()` method to disable current active activity component.