# Log.wtf vs. Unhandled Exception

Tags: android

I just learned about [`Log.wtf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) ("What a Terrible Failure" lol) and I'm wondering when I should use it.

1. What is the difference between calling `Log.wtf` with an exception and letting an exception go unhandled (crash)?
2. How does it affect crash reports in the Google Play Developer Console?
3. I usually throw an `IllegalStateException` for unexpected conditions. Should I consider calling `Log.wtf` instead?

**Edit:**

See also: [Under what circumstances will Android's Log.wtf terminate my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752642/under-what-circumstances-will-androids-log-wtf-terminate-my-app)

Answer (score 4):

<strike>What `Log.wtf` does is write the exception and its stack trace in the log, and only that. It neither catches nor throws exceptions. So</strike>

1. The difference is the exception is logged or not. The exception remains unhandled.
2. It doesn't affect crash reports.
3. If you wish to log it, go ahead. But you'll want to keep throwing `IllegalStateException`.

**EDIT**

I tried debugging and stepping into `Log.wtf` but no luck.

What I've found is pretty much what is answered in the linked question. It seems that in the "default terrible failure handling" `Log.wtf` creates an internal exception (`TerribleFailure`) which wraps any given exception. Then it calls `RuntimeInit.wtf()`. Its javadoc says:

> Report a serious error in the current process.  May or may not cause
>   the process to terminate (depends on system settings).

I guess the behavior of `Log.wtf` is up to the device manufacturer. My Sony C6503 doesn't seem to raise any exception or kill the process.

Some open source reference:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/RuntimeInit.java

Comment: Maybe Log.wtf doesn't throw the exception but it does terminate the app, at least sometimes. If it doesn't terminate by throwing the exception, then that would affect the crash report, if I get one at all.

Comment: @cambunctious yes, maybe so. From the code i linked, Android internals handles exceptions and kills the process in some cases

Comment: Is it possible for an implementation of Log.wtf to terminate the app without crashing and causing a crash report?

Comment: I'm actually shocked to find out this does anything other than log. It was supposed to be for errors that should never, ever happen but if it did then you most certainly want to know about it. Maybe the idea is crashing the app at the given spot would be better than crashing the app later from code that wasn't expecting the error (which would most certainly happen).

Comment: @cambunctious i guess not. i understand that any app termination via Log.wtf is abnormal, that is, a kind of crash, and it will always report

Comment: @DeeV I agree. The log functions should just log. Anything else is like wtf.

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled exceptions are not logged by default. `Log.wtf` may or may not crash the application. If you pass an exception to `Log.wtf` and it crashes, then you should get a stack trace similar to what you would get if the exception were not handled. After calling `Log.wtf`, you should (re)throw an exception if you want to ensure a crash (without catching it of course).

There may be specific use cases for `Log.wtf`, but if you are unsure, it's probably better to use `Log.e` instead.